# Spring NamespaceHandler and multiple property placeholders

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing as follows:

- register a NamespaceHandler (with all spring.x files, the handler is properly located and invoked)
- in the Parser registered by the namespace handler, I load an xml file containing bean definitions (rather than defining them programmatically):

  ```
  XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(parserContext.getRegistry());
  reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("definitions.xml"));
  ```
- definitions.xml contains a `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:.. />`
- the applicationContext.xml which invokes my handler needs to pass a property (e.g. `<foo:bar prop="${baz}" />`
- in the namespace handler I define an inline `PropertySource` and register it with the Environment, so that I can dynamically register a property that I need, which is based on the `prop` passed as attribute. I tried registering a String bean instead, but resolution fails.

The property placeholder resolution happens after bean definitions, so happens after my code in the namespace handler's parser is invoked.

However, this all fails. Multiple times, for multiple reasons. Here are they:

- if `<context:property-placeholder />` is defined without `ignore-unresolvable="true"` and `order`, the first placeholder configurer fails to find properties required by the 2nd one. This is logical, of course, and seems to be mandatory whenever multiple placeholder configurers are used
- because the dynamic property is based on the passed `prop`, it looks like `file://${prop}/foo", which means it is a nested property. You can't configure the behaviour of nested property resolution per configurer, which means even though`ignore-unresolvable` is true, nested properties are not ignored, and the whole thing fails.

The solution I found is to get the `AbstractEnvironment` in the namespace handler's parser, and set the call `env.setIgnoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders(true)`

This looks like a hack though. So my questions are:

- how to dynamically register properties that will later be resolved?
- how to configure ignoring nested property resolution per configurer?
- is there a better way to achieve what I need - namely, include a "bundle" of definitions via a custom namespace, and pass properties (loaded from file) to them?

P.S. Spring improvement request posted: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10654

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use custom prefix for your *namespace* property placeholder? That is the official way how to have multiple property placeholders in one context.

Comment: Do you still need answer to this question?